# PL/SQL: Having trouble creating procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, ssh

I'm having issues creating a simple procedure in oracle 10g

All I'm trying to do is this procedure:

```
create procedure greetings
is
begin
dbms_output.put_line('Hello');
end;
```

I type this into the prompt:

```
@proc1.sql
```

and I get only this:

```
6
```

and I'm unable to get back to the prompt again without ctrl+c. I know it's ghetto but I'm using SSH if that helps solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `/` on a line by itself after the final `end;` so sqlplus will know it's time to execute. (sqlplus somehow fails to know how to parse the language which is its sole purpose for existing, so it doesn't know that the last `end;` you entered is the one that terminates the `create` command.)

Comment: Regarding your parenthetical comment: sqlplus *doesn't parse* PL/SQL - it passes it to the database for parsing and execution. For example, `end;` might appear multiple times within a PL/SQL block or database package, but it doesn't mean that the compilation unit is finished.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. However, when I typed `exec greetings` all it displayed was `PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.` without the output I wanted displayed. @Wumpus Q. Wumbley

Comment: @user2853262 you need `set serveroutput on` or else `dbms_output` just goes nowhere.